# how to save variable as array into database

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

How i can save an array into database as string

```
col1 |  col2
-------------------
1    | array(1,2)
-------------------
2    | array(6,9)
```

all value in the array related together

Comment: Use serialize($array);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use serialize() and unserialize()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Your data would look like this:
a:2:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;}

Answer (score 0):

You can use either 
Serialize() and Unserialize()
you can use the php defualt implode function

[Implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

You can also use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

And when you are getting it back out of database u can convert it back to an array with [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize() before you insert the array. And unserialize() to get the data back as php array.